# Is there a text console alternative to Developer Tools of browsers?

Tags: javascript

I mean the "console" part of the Developer Tools of any browser. I would prefer to use a real text console, like Terminator / ROXTerm for manipulating on webpage objects / DOM which are currently opened in a browser.